# Правильно ли согласованы слова "происшествия" и "произошло" с числительными?

Tags: согласование, числительные

Так, в 2015 году на территории Республики Беларусь зарегистрировано 4119 дорожно-транспортных происшествия (ст.ст. 317-319, ст. 321 УК Республики Беларусь), из которых 1568 произошло с участием пешеходов.

Comment: По-моему, надо так: _…девятнадцать происшеств**ий**_.

Comment: @Буратино "*68 произошло" тоже корректно. Учите матчасть: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Comment: @oleedd Напишешь ответ? А то я не разберусь.

Comment: @Буратино Из информации по ссылке: На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на пассивность подлежащего, совместность действия действующих лиц, а также на количество, названное в подлежащем. Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться употреблением в качестве сказуемых **глаголов со значением бытия, наличия: *быть, существовать, иметься*** и др. *В результате урагана упало двадцать деревьев. На лекцию пришло именно пятьдесят человек, а не пятьдесят два. У существительного имеется двенадцать падежных форм.*